# SQL increment infrequently incorrect

Tags: sql

I am trying to maintain a ticketing system to keep track of Work Order numbers and every so often the count of the WO_NUM jumps. The WO_NUM should be the same as the WOID. But for some reason, after using this system for years, the WO_NUM started to be 1 greater than the WOID.

[The count for WO_NUM jumps by 2 instead of 1 from WO_NUM 229912 to WO_NUM 229914](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu8XU.png)

Then a few months later (128 days) to be exact, it jumps again this time to 2 greater than the WOID.

[The count for WO_NUM jumps from 239946 to 239948](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy2gn.png)

This happens again 18 days later, but this time to 3 greater than WOID with WO_NUM jumping from 241283 to 241285 while WOID increments normally from 241281 to 241822

And again 7 days later to 4 greater than WOID with WO_NUM jumps from 241897 to 241899 while WOID increments normally from 241894 to 241895.

This seems to keep getting further and further off and it his happening almost exponentially quicker. Any idea why this might be/how I might go about fixing it?

Comment: You've given us absolutely no information about how WO_NUM and WO_ID are generated, or even what RDBMS you are on.

Comment: Post the code used to build your table with the auto-increment fields.

Comment: Sorry, first time poster on SO. I'm on SQL Server Enterprise Manager and WO_NUM and WO_ID are ints that are incremented every time a new ticket is created. For some reason, somewhere along the way, WO_NUM seemingly randomly increments by 1 then 2 then 3 etc. and I need them to stay synced for my reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out myself. Turns out that if a work order was started and then cancelled without being saved WO_NUM was being incremented and not rolled back. Thanks to all that tried to help, sorry I didn't provide the requisite information. I'll make sure to do better next time!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an `IDENTITY` field in SQL Server or a similar auto-increment mechanism in another system, there is no guarantee that your IDs will be consecutive.  If you try to insert a new row and the insert fails, the ID that would have been used is skipped.  This is to allow another insert to begin while the other is in process without an ID collision.

If you *need* (not *want*) IDs to be consective then you'll have do do something like:

- Create a locking mechanism so that inserts are atomic.
- Use a key table that will store the next available ID for your table
- Only increment the key table if the insert succeeds.

That said, obviously this adds a lot of risk to your system, and doesn't address what happens if you *delete* a record.  I would reconsider whether you *need* consecutive IDs and whether that feature is worth the extra development and overhead.

Comment: Thank you.  I have dealt with many clients who are *obsessed* with having perfectly sequential IDs.  They are unique identifiers, that's it -- they should have no inherent meaning beyond that.

Comment: I understand that it doesn't need to be sequential, but I do need the WOID and the WO_NUM to be synced up for my reports WO_NUM increments by 4 and WOID increments by 1, Was more wondering how to fix that. Not

Comment: @PradyManepalli Then you need to show how WO_NUM is determined.  But what's the point of having a column that's the exact same value as another column?

Comment: @DStanley I am sorry if I am not being more helpful this is my first time working with this and it's a legacy system that my manager asked me to fix. This is the procedure that I found to determine the next WO_NUM. `CREATE PROC bosi_getNextAvailWONum
 @inWO_NUM INT,
 @outWO_NUM INT OUTPUT
AS
DECLARE @c INT
SELECT @c = COUNT(WO_NUM) FROM TASKS WHERE WO_NUM = @inWO_NUM
IF @c < 1
 BEGIN
  SET @outWO_NUM = @inWO_NUM
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
  SELECT @c = MAX(WO_NUM) FROM TASKS
  SET @outWO_NUM = (@c + 1)
 END
RETURN(0)
GO`